# can't figure out mistake in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to run this loop ,but i keep getting an error :

identifier expected

'.class' expected

both on line 4

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] x = {98, 30, 97, 10, 5};
            int[] y = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0, int j = 4 ; i <= 4 && j >= 0; i++,j-- ) 
            {
            System.out.print(x[i]);

            }
        }
```

Comment: That is a "main" method. Is it inside a class? eg `public class MyClass { <your main method> }`?

Comment: for(int i=0,j=4  .  .   will do

Comment: Don't do weird things. You'll remain with no friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type declaration is only allowed once in the `for` loop [initialization expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

```
for (int i = 0, j = 4; i <= 4 && j >= 0; i++, j--)
```